# Удалить n-e количество одинаковых элементов в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, матрицы, методы, криптография

Всем привет! Есть массив, где есть n-e количество одинаковых элементов. Как их удалить?
Допустим есть фраза:
"Раз#уме#етс#я, #мне# не# со#ста#вит# тр#уда# пр#едл#ожи#ть #им #нес#кол#ько# ка#нди#дат#ур!#"
где нужно удалить все символы "#", чтобы получось
"Разумеется, мне не составит труда предложить им несколько кандидатур!"
Пробовал сделать через splice, но работает очень криво.

```
for(let i = 0; i < matrici*m; i++) {
    shifr2.splice(shifr2.indexOf('#',0),1);
}
shifr2 = shifr2.join('');
alert("Зашифрованное сообщение: " + shifr);
console.log(shifr2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое делать так:

```
const str = "Раз#уме#етс#я, #мне# не# со#ста#вит# тр#уда# пр#едл#ожи#ть #им #нес#кол#ько# ка#нди#дат#ур!#"

strnew = str.replace(/\#/g, '');
console.log(strnew);
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
const TEXT = "Раз#уме#етс#я, #мне# не# со#ста#вит# тр#уда# пр#едл#ожи#ть #им #нес#кол#ько# ка#нди#дат#ур!#"

const removeUnnecessarySymbol = (str, symbolToRemove) => {
  let result = ""

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] !== symbolToRemove) {
      result += str[i]
    }
  }

  return result
}

console.log('result:', removeUnnecessarySymbol(TEXT, "#"))
```